# MFC dialog display 8 bit buffer

Tags: mfc, dib

Added a picture control to my MFC dialog. Set its type to Frame. Need to display 8 bit buffer  (NOT LOADED From file) on the picture control.  The image is scaled down, repeated , tilted diagonally. Not correct. I could not make it fit the control properly. resized the control but still the same problem.

```cpp
w = 750;
h = 850;
bpp = 8

void CDispDlg::BuildINfoAndDisp(int w, int h)
{
    m_pbmi = (BITMAPINFO*) new BYTE[sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + 256) * sizeof(RGBQUAD)];
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.bSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bpp;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biXpelsPerMeter = 0;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biYpelsPerMeter = 0;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i< 256; i++)
    {
        m_pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = i;
        m_pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = i;
        m_pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBRed = i;
        m_pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = 0;
        
    }
    
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
    m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -h;
    
    CClientDC dc(GetDlgItem(IDC_PicCntrl_DSIP));
    
    CRect rect;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_PicCntrl_DSIP)->GetClientRect(&rect);
    
    SetStrechBltMode(dc.GetSafeHdc(), COLORNOCOLOR);
    StretchBIBits(dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0 ,0 , rect.Width, rect.Height, 0,0, m_wImage, m_hImage, &m_U8imageBuf, m_pbmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out how many typos there are in this expression: `new BYTE(sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + 256) * sizeof(RGBQUAD)];`.

Comment: *"the same problem"* - What *is* the problem?

Comment: corrected a typo.  Had to type it in. why the image shows up diagonally?.

Comment: Scanlines need to be `DWORD`-aligned. If they aren't, the rendered image may appear skewed. 750 isn't an even multiple of 4. It would help if you provided an image of the result.

Comment: made it work by mapping the 8 bit image buffer to 24 bit image buffer. Will check into the scan lines.  Is there any way to get image X and Y by getting the point coordinate on the picture control?.